# EventKit reminder event with alarm without the hour?

Tags: swift, swift5, eventkit

How to add a reminder using EventKit in iOS 13 without the hour part in the alarm, so it reminds at the default user-selected time?
This code creates a new event, but it also sets the alarm to run at the midnight (`self.date` is at midnight).

```
let event: EKReminder = EKReminder(eventStore: eventStore)
event.title = "Hello World!"
event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: self.date)
event.addAlarm(alarm)
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44217470/4728300

Comment: Unfortunately, this one adds the event to the calendar, while I need to create a reminder :/